# Clearwater IMS Homer & Homestead Module installation error

Tags: sip, restcomm, ims

I have Followed the below path http://clearwater.readthedocs.org/en/stable/Manual_Install/ for installation of Clearwater IMS node-specific modules. But when i was trying to install Homer & Homestead getting as connection refused.

```
TCP poll failed to 127.0.0.1 9160
nc: connect to 127.0.0.1 port 9160 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
Failed to connect to '127.0.0.1:7199': Connection refused
```

Due to which i am not able to proceed further.

Can anyone help me here.

Comment: I have the same error in install. It eventually times out, and after installing clearwater-etcd I try to propagate the shared config to all nodes, though it does not propagate to the homestead node. Logs contain `2016-05-04 15:09:08.387076 D | rafthttp: failed to dial fbacc1114b33b094 on stream Message (cluster ID mismatch)
2016-05-04 15:09:08.387160 E | rafthttp: request sent was ignored (cluster ID mismatch: remote[fbacc1114b33b094]=f7b980fbe9185dd3, local=3138b545804347d)`

Comment: homestead is dependent on Cassandra. so if Cassandra is not running first then the homestead service will not be able to. check with `sudo monit summary` or `sudo service --status-all` whether Cassandra is running. And for Cassandra to run and operate normally, `clearwater-cluster-manager` service should be running.

Answer (score 0):

the error comes sometimes when your port is not feee or port is using by some other services check once port is free or not